# how can i hold pointer object in array?

Tags: c++

I'm a newbie. since my code is so long I can't edit it for being reproducible so I will show you what I did in a simple way

I have a Team class. I want to hold all my objects in an array so that I can reach them somewhere else and map for some data.
so I did a function basically doing this (exactly this part b[1] = a;)

```
int* a; // represent my object

int *b = new int[2]; //represent my static object pointer

b[1] = a;
```

error saying cant assign int = *int
yes absolutely true but I have to hold my object in the array. and I thought this could work but no... is there a way to hold an object in an array or can I say give me space for *int, during pointer initializing?

Comment: What does "I have to hold my object in the array" mean?

Comment: `int* b[2];  b[0]=a;  b[1]=a1;` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way would be to use `std::vector` to hold your class objects. The **advantage** of using a `std::vector` is that then you won't have to deal with memory management explicitly. `vector` will take care of it.

In addition, i will also recommend using **smart pointers**.

To solve your error above you can use the following example:

```
    int i = 0, j = 0;//int objects
    
    int* p = &i, *q = &j; //pointer to int objects

    int **b = new int*[2]; //note i have added * on both the left and right hand side.  

    b[0] = p;
    b[1] = q;
    //dont forget to use delete below
```

Note you should use `std::vector` and smart pointers, but i have added an example so that you can see how to remove the error and use this example as a reference.

Comment: And at that point you're better of just storing the whole objects in the vector. Because it will become increasingly unclear who owns the pointers. If pointers are needed the model ownership with std::unique_ptr. Look at all things pointer/new/delete here : https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines

Comment: @PepijnKramer Yes `vector` are the way to go. I already added a note at the top of my answer. Now, i have added a note at the end of my answer too saying that this is just so that OP can see how to remove the said error and use this example as a reference.

Comment: It was more to clarify what you had, it is possible to have a std::vector of pointers if you design for it. (none owning references basically). But it is usually not the first thing one should do.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Ofcourse it is possible to have a `vector` of pointers. But i only wanted to show how to solve the error in OP's current program and keep my answer to the point.